# Порядок команд для SQL запроса

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Здравствуйте, помогите разобраться с запросом.

```
$queryString = "SELECT
                  id, Name, whoUpload, link, likes, comments, date, time
                FROM
                  table
                LIMIT
                  '$start', '$how'
                WHERE 
                  whoUpload = '{$_POST['username']}'
                ORDER BY
                  `id` DESC";
```

Выражаясь человеческим языком: Начни мне выводить записи со `$start` в количестве `$how` штук пользователя `User` да так, чтобы свежие были в начале.

Собственно, до `LIMIT '$start', '$how'` все работало. Куда я только не пробовал его запихнуть, может надо как-то по другому?

Comment: А есть какой-то скрытый смысл делать столбцы `date` и `time` вместо одного `datetime`?  и почему у вас "свежие" это значит с последними вставленными айдишниками, а не по времени?

Comment: Потому что я еще очень зеленый :D А почему по id нельзя судить о свежести записи?)

Comment: Можно, если даты нет... А если есть поля с датой, то, например, можно запросто в конец таблицы навставлять записи с датой меньше,чем в начале (по разным причинам такое может быть)...... и тогда получится, вы хотите вытащить все новые добавленные  комментарии, а вместо этого вы вытащите старье.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский в нашей таблице не актуально, но большое спасибо за пояснение :)

Answer (score 4):

Лимит должен быть в конце.

```
SELECT
  `id`, `Name`, `whoUpload`, `link`, `likes`, `comments`, `date`, `time`
FROM
  table
WHERE
  whoUpload = '{$_POST['username']}'
ORDER BY
  `id` DESC
LIMIT
 '$start', '$how'
```

Comment: Свежие - не значит с самым большим айдишником...

Comment: @АлексейШиманский  согласен но и ответ в принципе правильный

Comment: Согласен id не всегда соответствует наиболее свежим записям. Но назначение полей нам неизвестно. Не факт что `date` и `time` это время вставки или обновления записи. К томуже, @Ivan Blohin изначально сортировал по id и говорит что это работает, но выдаёт много записей.